# What's the fastest way to tell whether two strings or binary files are different?

Tags: c++, string, comparison, binaryfiles

I'm writing a unit test and need to compare a result file to a golden file. What's the easiest way to do so?

So far I have (for Linux environment):

```cpp
int result = system("diff file1 file2");
```

They are different if `result != 0`.

Comment: That sounds like a plausible way to compare two files, yes.

Comment: There are various standard options of `diff` to suppress output. Use them, if you call it through `system`.

Comment: You can use `cmp` instead of `diff`.

Comment: Absolute fastest, if these are big files, may be check that they are the same length, then `mmap()` them and call `memcmp()`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want a pure c++ solution, I would do something like this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

template<typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2>
bool
range_equal(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
        InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2)
{
    while(first1 != last1 && first2 != last2)
    {
        if(*first1 != *first2) return false;
        ++first1;
        ++first2;
    }
    return (first1 == last1) && (first2 == last2);
}

bool compare_files(const std::string& filename1, const std::string& filename2)
{
    std::ifstream file1(filename1);
    std::ifstream file2(filename2);

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin1(file1);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin2(file2);

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

    return range_equal(begin1, end, begin2, end);
}
```

It avoids reading the entire file into memory, and stops as soon as the files are different (or at end of file).  The range_equal because `std::equal` doesn't take a pair of iterators for the second range, and isn't safe if the second range is shorter.

Comment: Can you explain why as `end` you use an unitialized iterator? OP mentions binary files, would it make sense using [`std::ios::binary`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5420568/2436175)? P.S.: I would note this is not the fastest, as it checks one byte at the time also for big files. But as a simple solution seems excellent.

Comment: @Antonio An  uninitialized std::istreambuf_iterator is the end iterator.  For performance, the code assumes that your stream is doing the buffering (for example, in many implementations of of `std::ifstream`, the underlying stream is buffered).

Comment: How about md5 compare? Does the computing of md5 also read the entire file? So it doesn't faster than directly compare byte-chunk of the files?

Answer (score 7):

Developing from [DaveS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15119347/2436175), and as first thing [checking file size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5840160/2436175):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

bool compare_files(const std::string& filename1, const std::string& filename2)
{
    std::ifstream file1(filename1, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary); //open file at the end
    std::ifstream file2(filename2, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary); //open file at the end
    const std::ifstream::pos_type fileSize = file1.tellg();

    if (fileSize != file2.tellg()) {
        return false; //different file size
    }

    file1.seekg(0); //rewind
    file2.seekg(0); //rewind

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin1(file1);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin2(file2);

    return std::equal(begin1,std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),begin2); //Second argument is end-of-range iterator
}
```

(I wonder if before rewinding, `fileSize` could be used to create a more efficient end of stream iterator, which, by knowing the stream length, would allow `std::equal` to process more bytes at the time).

Comment: Why not simply `if (file2.tellg() != file2.tellg())`? How storing first in the `fileSize` helps?

Comment: @iammilind Thanks for pointing out that, there was an error in the post script after the code, now it should be clear why I wanted to underline that being the size of the file.

Answer (score 2):

one way to prevent reading both files is to pre-compute the golden file into a hash, eg a md5. Then you only have to check the test file. Note, this may be slower than just reading both files!

Alternatively, layer your checking - look at the file sizes, if they're different then the files are different and you can avoid a lengthy read-and-compare operation.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <iterator>


bool equal_files(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
  std::ifstream stream{a};
  std::string file1{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
  
  stream = std::ifstream{b};
  std::string file2{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
  
  return file1 == file2;
}
```

I suspect this to be not as fast as `diff`, but it avoids calling
`system`. It should be sufficient for a test-case, though.

Comment: You probably want to include `iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an overkill but you could build a table of hashes SHA-256 using boost/bimap and boost/scope_exit.

Here is a video how to do this by Stephan T Lavavej (starts at 8.15):
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-5-of-n

For more info about algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2