# What is a good way to compare data before encryption and after decryption

Tags: encryption, file-io, compare, crypto++

I am running a lot of algorithms from Crypto++. I am Encrypting, then decrypting like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng_blowfish;

    SecByteBlock key_blowfish(Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    prng_blowfish.GenerateBlock( key_blowfish, key_blowfish.size() );

    byte iv_blowfish[ Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE ];
    prng_blowfish.GenerateBlock( iv_blowfish, sizeof(iv_blowfish) );

    string ifilename = "sample_files/1MB.jpg";
    string cipher = "1MB.enc";
    string rfilename = "r1MB.jpg";

    try {

    EAX< Blowfish >::Encryption e_blowfish;
    e_blowfish.SetKeyWithIV( key_blowfish, key_blowfish.size(), iv_blowfish, sizeof(iv_blowfish) );

    std::ifstream ifile(ifilename.c_str(), ios::binary);
    std::ifstream::pos_type size = ifile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end).tellg();
    ifile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    FileSource fs1( ifilename.c_str(), true, new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter( e_blowfish, new FileSink(cipher.c_str()) ) );

    EAX< Blowfish >::Decryption d_blowfish;
    d_blowfish.SetKeyWithIV( key_blowfish, key_blowfish.size(), iv_blowfish, sizeof(iv_blowfish) );

    FileSource fs2( cipher.c_str(), true, new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter( d_blowfish, new StringSink( rfilename ), AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION ) ); 

    } catch (const Exception& ex) {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

I need to make sure that everything is working properly. I would like to compare the file that is being read in from before it is encrypted to the file after it has been decrypted so  that I know everything is working properly. Can somebody create an example of how I would be able to do this?

Comment: The simplest way is to compute a hash before and after. md5, sha, something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare two files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163611/compare-two-files)

Comment: @j.atec - "... can somebody create an example... " - You have to do your own work. I set a bad precedent with the extra help on your Crypo++ questions because its not an easy library. But others are probably not going to be so accommodating, especially on basic C++ questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately not possible to check if your encryption routines are properly implemented or not by just looking at the output. There are few pitfalls you can - and should - check, though:

- Encrypt an all zero file and see if there are any discernible patterns. ECB shows repeating blocks there.
- Encrypt the same file twice. The ciphertext should *not* have any visible similarity. If they are the same then you probably use the same IV or nonce multiple times.
- Basically the same problem as above: Without any outside knowledge (package counter, etc.) the ciphertext will always be longer than the plaintext, because of an IV or nonce that has to be transmitted alongside.
- If you are using authenticated encryption (as after skimming your code I believe you do) change a byte and verify that it indeed results in an error message.

But as I've said above these are only negative criteria. A lot of other errors will not show in such a way. For example if you use the current time as an entropy source for your key you will see the exact same behaviour as with proper entropy.

Comment: I believe j.atec wants to make sure the file round trips properly: "I would like to compare the file that is being read in from before it is encrypted to the file after it has been decrypted".

Comment: Huh, I thoroughly misunderstood his question reading "before it is encrypted to the file after it has been *en*crypted". @jww

Comment: Yeah, j.atec has some interesting requirements. I think they stem from his benchmarking.